# At a total loss with java list processing code

Tags: java, arrays, list, shift

Okay, this is probably going to come across as a really easy question, but honestly I'm new to coding and I've run up against a brick wall here. I need to insert a value into an array, shift the data to the right, and update the size of the array. The professor provided comments for us to structure our code around, and I've got most of it, but this last part is killing me. Can anyone help? Here's the code (the relevant portion is under //insert value and shift data...etc):

```java
public class List {

    // Declare variables
    private int size = 0;
    private int maxSize = 100;
    private int[] data;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // constructors
    public List() {
        data = new int[maxSize];
    }

    public List(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        data = new int[maxSize];
    }

    // methods
    // Adds a value into the array and updates the size
    public boolean add(int value) {
        if (size == maxSize) {
            System.out.println("Cannot add value since the list is full");
            return false;
        }
        data[size] = value;
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    // add multiple values to the list obtained from the keyboard
    public void addValues() {
        // declare local variables
        int count = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter multiple integers separated by spaces");
        String line = keyboard.nextLine();
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(line);
        try {
            while (scanLine.hasNext()) {
                data[size] = scanLine.nextInt();
                count++;
                size++;
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiobe) {
            System.out.println("Only " + count + " values could be added before the list is full");
            return;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Only " + count + " values could be added due to invalid input");
            return;
        }
    }

    // This will print all the elements in the list
    public void print() {
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // This methods returns the index of the key value if found in the list
    // and returns -1 if the key value is not in the list
    public int find(int key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (data[i] == key) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // This methods deletes the given value if exists and updates the size.
    public boolean delete(int value) {
        int index = find(value);
        if (index == -1) {
            System.out.println("The specified value is not in the list");
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < size - 1; i++) {
            data[i] = data[i + 1];
        }
        size--;
        return true;
    }

    // This methods inserts the value at the given index in the list
    public boolean insertAt(int index, int value) {
        // validate index value and insertability
        if (index < 0 || index > size || size == maxSize) {
            System.out.println("Invalid index or list is already full");
            return false;
        }
        // insert value and shift data to the right and update the size

        return true;
    }

    // This method removes the value at given index and shifts the data as needed
    public boolean removeAt(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < size) {
            for (int i=index+1; i<size; i++)
                data[i-1] = data[i];
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // This method sorts the values in the list using selection sort
    public void sort() {
        int temp;
        for (int j=size; j>1; j--) {
            int maxIndex = 0;
            for (int i=1; i<j; i++)
                if (data[maxIndex] < data[i])
                    maxIndex = i;
            temp = data[j-1];
            data[j-1] = data[maxIndex];
            data[maxIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize if the code is structured really horribly as well, by the way, I was unsure how to format it on this site so it looked right.

Comment: No-one is just going to do this for you, please let us know what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: the class is a bit inconsistent, add will not add new values when the list is full. addValues does not care about that. What shall happen with the overflow when insertAt is called and the list is full ? The last element gets kicked out ? Generally it helps most, if you write down what the solution would be (in words, pseudo code or what so ever) - dont try to solve the problem at start with the code you will write then

Answer (score 0):

// insert value and shift data to the right and update the size

// I think the size is globally declared right?

size++;

```
for(int i=size - 1; i < 0; i--) {
    data[i] = data[i - 1];
}
data[index] = value;
```

If you have a max size there will also be a check for size <= maxSize. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Think below answer should help. As there is already a size check, no need to check it again

```
public boolean insertAt(int index, int value) {
    // validate index value and insertability
  if (index < 0 || index > 5) {
    System.out.println("Invalid index or list is already full");
    return false;
  }
  // insert value and shift data to the right and update the size

  for(int i=index;i<size;i++) {
      data[++i] = data[i];
  }
  data[index] = value;

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean insertAt(int index, int value) {
        // validate index value and insertability
        if (index < 0 || index > size || size == maxSize) {
            System.out.println("Invalid index or list is already full");
            return false;
        }
        // insert value and shift data to the right and update the size
           for (int i=size - 1; i > index; i--)
           data[i+1] = data[i];
           data[index] = value
           size++;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some comments how it would resolve the issue?

Comment: I think your professor want you to complete the "insertAt" function.this is my code